Greek TV game show about cooking and hosting
So I was in Australia a couple of years ago and I saw this TV show on "SBS1" which is one of the networks they broadcast there. The format for the station seemed to be a hodge-podge of international shows: German, Japanese, Italian (I think), and Greek.
Anyway, I saw this one show titled "Kati Ynvetal" (phonetic) that I think was from Greece. "Something Baked" in english according to google translator. It was a fun show. Every night of the week, a group of five would rotate hosting a dinner: Complete three course meal including cocktails and a party favor. After dinner, the guests would wander through the bedrooms while the host was prepping dessert and learn a little about their host. Afterwards, during the ride home, the guests would rate the evening and give a 1-10 score. At the end of the week the winner got a cash prize.  The video quality wasnt too great, and the peoples clothing looked a little bit dated, so it makes me think the show was a little older (maybe mid/late 90s.  I dont stay current with Greek fashion trends).  The whole show was in Greek but it was subtitled in English.
   So when I get back to the homeland I begin my search so I can watch other weeks episodes.
This is where my problem begins and I'm wondering if anyone here can help me out. I cannot find ANYTHING about this show. I've dug and dug and still can't find anything relevant to the show. It's to a point that if my wife didn't see it too, I would believe that I went crazy and experienced recurring hallucinations. 
   Any leads on this would be greatly appreciated.
   Thank you in advance. 

This sounds like Kati psinetai ("Something's cooking") that went on the air in 2009 and is the popular Greek version of Come Dine With Me that follows its format faithfully:

A group of five strangers, each an amateur chef, compete to host the best dinner party, each party solely for the competitors and to be held on consecutive evenings. With a set amount of money provided for the party, each host must submit a menu in advance of the week, the menu to consist of at least a starter, a main and a dessert/pudding. At the end of each party, each guest rates the party on a scale of one to ten inclusive.

Here's a long clip from the show:




THANK YOU!!! This is pretty much it!!  Looks like it follows the format to a tee. The little graphics at the bottom of the screen even say "kati ynvetal" which was the title of the show I watched.  Although, this seems to be the modern version of what I saw:  The clothing, hairstyles, and home decor are definitely more modern.  Thanks again!!

@Justinius No problem, glad you found it. :) "kati ynvetal" Ah, I understand the confusion now (the greek letters for 'psinetai' do kinda look like that).
